# How to properly control snmptrapd within a bash script

Tags: snmp

I am trying to monitor snmp notifications using *snmptrapd*.
It is ran using bash script and I add the '&' at the end of the *snmptrapd* line (1) to run it in the background. This way I start listening to the 162 port and the rest of the script can be executed without being blocked. The problem is I can not figure out how to properly terminate or stop the *snmptrapd* after I finished my test (since it runs on the background). The work flow is something like this:

```
1    sudo snmptrapd -f -C -c my.conf -L f my.log &
2    # do test 1
3    sudo service snmptrapd stop;
4    # analyze the .log file
5    sudo service snmptrapd start;
6    # do test 2 
7    sudo service snmptrapd stop;
8    # analyze the .log file
9    ...
```

but line (3) does not seem to stop the trapd - I can see that the notifications are kept being received. Not sure if line (5) starts "unstopped" *smnptrapd*, but the line (7) seem to stop the service - I can see that the notifications are not being received anymore (using wireshark). In addition to that, the two files referenced in line (1) are with the "locked" icon.

I would like to be able to stop snmptrapd and make changes and/or create new files and then restart the snmptrapd again to run the next test.

1. Why do I get this inconsistent behavior when the first "stop" command does not seem to have any effect, and the second one does.
2. Is there a better way to control this process?
3. How to make the files "unlocked", so I could delete them or edit?

Comment: I'm only guessing, as I don't run `snmptrapd`, but it may be that the initial run does not start it as a service, so the first `stop` doesn't work; whereas the second `stop` follows the `start`, which does make it a service.

Comment: @AFH Very likely. Then, when I add another round of start and stop at line (9), the device does not start anymore.